# Organize MySQL results by DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Using PHP I am trying to find a way to combine the results of multiple MySQL queries and put them into one array ordered by their DateTime timestamps which in the database is saved under 'timestamp'.

My Code:

```
        $reactions = DB::query('SELECT * FROM reactions WHERE poster_id=:userid', array(':userid' => $userid));
        $comments = DB::query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE poster_id=:userid', array(':userid' => $userid));
        $mentions = DB::query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:users , users)', array(':users' => $userid));
        $postMentions = DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:users , users)', array(':users' => $userid));
```

Edit:
Updated Code

```
$reactions = "'SELECT timestamp as date FROM reactions WHERE poster_id=:userid', array(':userid' => $userid)";
        $comments = "'SELECT timestamp as date FROM comments WHERE poster_id=:userid', array(':userid' => $userid)";
        $mentions = "'SELECT timestamp as date FROM comments WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:users , users)', array(':users' => $userid)";
        $postMentions = "'SELECT timestamp as date FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:users , users)', array(':users' => $userid)";

        $sql = 'SELECT timestamp FROM ('.$reactions.' UNION ALL '.$comments.' UNION ALL '.$mentions.' UNION ALL '.$postMentions.') as combined order by timestamp desc';

        $result = DB::query($sql, array());

        print_r($result);
```

Comment: Have u tried "union" in mysql?

Comment: @KimberleeHo Nope, I've never heard of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve same through UNION. Try below code snippet...

```
$reactions = 'SELECT reactions.date as date FROM reactions WHERE poster_id=:userid', array(':userid' => $userid);
$comments = 'SELECT comments.date as date FROM comments WHERE poster_id=:userid', array(':userid' => $userid);
$mentions = 'SELECT comments.date as date FROM comments WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:users , users)', array(':users' => $userid);
$postMentions = 'SELECT posts.date as date FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:users , users)', array(':users' => $userid);

$sql = SELECT combined.date from (".$reactions." UNION ALL ".$comments." UNION ALL ".$mentions." UNION ALL ".$postMentions.") as combined order by combined.date desc;
```

Comment: How would I implement this into my code? I am using query from my DB class. Also, I don't use combined.date or any of those, are they needed?

Comment: Add this line  `$result = DB::query($sql);` this should execute your query.....and  combined is an table alias here.

Comment: I tried implementing it but it gave the page an 'HTTP ERROR 500', I edited my updated code into the main question.